# Dell Laptop won't  shutdown / restart by itself

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, shutdown, reboot, power-management

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 64-bit on my Dell Studio 1569. Before this I ran ubuntu 11.04 64-bit.

Every time I shutdown, or restart it goes through the usual processes, and shows no error

( I watch the shutdown messages by pressing the Page Down key).

When it gets to the point where it says "Will now halt," or "will now restart" it fails to do so.

This is a bit annoying since at this point I have to manually cut the power by holding down the power button. I never had any issue like this in 11.04. Also, hibernation no longer works. It was extremely slow in 11.04 (Slower than a cold boot) but it worked. Now nothing works. Please help!

Comment: strange problems might be solved with a fresh install! It's always safer to make a fresh install.

Comment: I have the same issue on a fresh install. Different Dell model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noapic"
```

save the file and finally again in the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your laptop and after the next boot check if your laptop is power down by itself.